# How to get the refresh status of each power query of a excel workbook via VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, qt

I am doing some PoC test for a PowerQuery project via VBA. Here are the requirement

1. Need to refresh the queries in a given order
2. The query behind needs to start once the previous query finishes and successes, if fails, need to provide error reason. Msgbox(query name, refresh status, error reason if applied)

I tried to use AfterRefresh event But I couldn't get the individual query refresh status, just overall status. And I tried to disable the background fresh , but didn't find a way if it worked or not. Please could I have your help. Thanks in advance, Here are the codes:

1. Class Modules( I expect to show the queryname in the Msgbox, how could add ?)

### I found the BackgroundQuery=True must be set. otherwise, if it set to False the afterfresh event will not be triggered. I got lost....

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents MyQuery As QueryTable

'Public s_QueryName As String

Private Sub MyQuery_AfterRefresh(ByVal Success As Boolean)

    
    If Success Then
        MsgBox (s_QueryName & "   has been refreshed.")
       ' count = count + 1
        'MsgBox (count)
        
    Else
    
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub MyQuery_BeforeRefresh(Cancel As Boolean)
    If MsgBox("Refresh query?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then
        Cancel = True
        
    Else
    
    End If
End Sub

---------------------------------------------------------------------


2. Modules
-------------------------------------------------------------------
   Option Explicit

Dim colQueries As New Collection
Public s_QueryName As String
'Public count As Integer

Sub InitializeQueries()


Dim clsQ As clsQuery
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim QT As QueryTable
Dim LO As ListObject


For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each QT In WS.QueryTables
        MsgBox (WS.Name)
        Set clsQ = New clsQuery
        Set clsQ.MyQuery = QT
        colQueries.Add clsQ
    Next QT


    For Each LO In WS.ListObjects
        MsgBox (WS.Name)
        Set QT = LO.QueryTable
        Set clsQ = New clsQuery
        Set clsQ.MyQuery = QT
        colQueries.Add clsQ
        
    Next LO
Next WS


End Sub


Private Sub Button1_Click()
    Call InitializeQueries
   ' ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query - CombineErrorlists").Refresh
    
    Dim bRfresh As Boolean
   s_QueryName = "Query - CombineErrorlists"

    With ThisWorkbook.Connections("Query - CombineErrorlists").OLEDBConnection
        'bRfresh = .BackgroundQuery
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .Refresh
        '.BackgroundQuery = bRfresh

    End With
 '  MsgBox ("CombineErrorlists" & "refeesh done")
    
    
   ' Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 15, Now)
    
    
    s_QueryName = "Query - FilesTransform"
    
 '   ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query - FilesTransform").Refresh
    
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Connections("Query - FilesTransform").OLEDBConnection
        'bRfresh = .BackgroundQuery
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .Refresh
        '.BackgroundQuery = bRfresh

    End With

'    MsgBox ("FilesTransform" & " refeesh done")

    
End Sub
```